# Calculations based on Quartiles (Any percentile)

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

For example

```
summary(mtcars$mpg)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.40   15.43   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90
```

I need to calculate of mean and standard deviation of "disp" variable of each quartile based on variable "mpg".

Comment: Do you need `mtcars %>% group_by(mpg_grp = cut(mpg, breaks = quantile(mpg))) %>% summarise(disp_mean = mean(disp), disp_sd = sd(disp))`

Comment: Yes thanks - i was not aware of the cut function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `breaks` with the `quantile` of 'mpg' in `cut`, use that as grouping variable to `summarise` the `mean` and `sd` of 'disp'

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     group_by(mpg_grp = cut(mpg, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(mpg), Inf))) %>% 
     summarise(disp_mean = mean(disp), disp_sd = sd(disp))
```